# Scrolling of TableView not fluid when MKMapView is loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview, smooth-scrolling

I have a `TableView` that contains an `MKMapView` in the most bottom cell. While scrolling, when the `MKMapView` appears on screen, there is a big lag until the `MKMapView` is fully loaded.

How can I prevent this lag ?

Here is my map code inside of `viewDidLoad`:

```
// Map Cell
self.mapCell.accessoryType = .None
self.mapCell.userInteractionEnabled = false
self.mapCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: 10.875,
    longitude: 5.986
)

let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.4, 0.4)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location
annotation.title = "Title"
annotation.subtitle = "Subtitle"

self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(self.mapCell.frame.origin.x, self.mapCell.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 300)
self.mapView.delegate = self
self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
self.mapCell.addSubview(mapView)
```

Comment: I suggest you to disable animations in mapView.setRegion. You probably doing to much work on UIThread and thats why it has no time to render all of this.

Comment: @razor118 This doesn't change anything, but in addition I get this warning: "Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first."